# Google Api is not giving location

Tags: google-maps, google-api, geolocation, google-location-services

I am using google API to get location in my project. It gives location sometimes but most of the time it does not give any location. and   from today it is giving server return an error 403 forbidden. 
When i am hitting the URL in my browser it is giving location.
I am not using any key for my API can it cause this issue.

Just to add- 
I get the lat and long from my api and then i get the location from google api and stores it in my database.

What i am doing is:-

```
public static string getGoogleLocationByLogLat(string log, string lat)
{

    try
    {
         if (log == "")
    {
        log = "0.0";
    }
    if (lat == "")
    {
        lat = "0.0";
    }

    XmlTextReader xReader;
    bool element = false;
    string location = "", time, GL, parentEmail, respDateTime;
    string parentElementName = "";
    string childElementName = "";
    string childElementValue = "", prmryCntact = "";

    string url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" + lat + "," + log + "&sensor=true";

    xReader = new XmlTextReader(url);

        while (xReader.Read())
        {

            if (xReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {

                if (element)
                {
                    parentElementName = parentElementName + childElementName + "<br>";
                }

                element = true;

                childElementName = xReader.Name;

            }

            else if (xReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text | xReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.CDATA)
            {

                element = false;

                childElementValue = xReader.Value;

                if (childElementName == "formatted_address")
                {
                    location = childElementValue;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    if (location.Trim() == "")
    {
        location = "Location not found";
    }

    return location;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "LOCATION NOT FOUND";
    }
}
```

Comment: Read https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro as stated there, you need an api key.

Comment: @ThomasS.E. I read the tried with a api key but after one hit it is asking for billing account.  I am also getting location without api key *sometimes ( most of the time i do not get location). I want to say that is there any solution of my problem without adding a api key.

Answer (score 1):

Add your API key

```
&key=yourkey
```

With the latest policy updates to the maps api, i believe this must be the case that you're hitting...

Also use https ... It's permitted only over https

Comment: I have added a api key and after one hit it is saying  " You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an active billing account:".  Do i have to pay for using google api?

Comment: Google has changed its quota policy, instead of free requests you now have to activate a billing account, and you get $ 200 credit for each month. When exceeding this amount, it will be charged to your billing account.

You can also have a look at: https://mapsplatformtransition.withgoogle.com/

Comment: You need an active billing account... You'll get monthly 200$ and your requests will be used from this credit... Only when you exhaust this will you get charged

Comment: Check the link which Thomas provided

Comment: @ThomasS.E. my client is asking for a proper  facts. can you provide me any link other than google document where it is clearly written that without API key causing this type of issues.

Comment: That's the official document buddy... There's a page where they give you quota information, you'll find it in their billing and prices section.